# AWS Amplify UI Customization in React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to change the UI in react using aws amplify

```
import * as React from "react"
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {CustomSignUp} from "./component/CustomSignUp"

import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

import {
    ConfirmSignIn,
    ConfirmSignUp,
    ForgotPassword,
    SignIn,
    SignUp,
    VerifyContact,
    withAuthenticator,
} from "aws-amplify-react";
import {CustomSignIn} from "./component/CustomSignIn";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig)

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
        </div>
    );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App,false, [
    <CustomSignUp override={'SignUp'} />,
    <CustomSignIn override={'SignIn'} />,
    <ConfirmSignIn />,
    <VerifyContact />,
    <ConfirmSignUp />,
    <ForgotPassword />,
])
```

**I am confused on what exactly to add in CustomSignUp.js or CustomSignIn.js file
I want to change the UI completely.
Can someone give an example what should I add in CustomSignUp and CustomSignIn page.**